# Where is the newly created build definition file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, tfsbuild, msdeploy

In Visual Studio 2013,
   Team Explorer,
I created a new build definition called Release. Now I want to edit the XML build file associated with this file so I click on "Edit Build Definition..." which shows me to the editing form for this build but not the XML file. Where is this proj file located. The project is already on TFS. Should I Check-in something which I am not aware of to be able to edit the xml content? Can't find this build?

Comment: If you are looking for the tfsbuild.proj files, then from TFS2010 build definitions make use of XAML files.

Comment: As other users have said, from TFS 2010 upwards, builds no longer use a TFSBuild.proj file. Add some more detail about what you are trying to change and someone will be able to advise you on the best method.

Answer (score 0):

The default build templates in TFS are WF XAML files and are only the templates for the build process.  There is no XML file there for you to edit, the build details are stored within TFS.

Depending on what you are tying to do, you can look at editing or [creating new Workflow templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd647551%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), note that changes made to a template will effect all builds associated with the template.